# Drop shadow in UICollectionViewCell not accurate

Tags: ios, swift

I am not able to get accurate shadow for collectionview cell which has a UIImage and a label.

I have collection view for which shadow appears properly. Below are code snippets for both and screenshot showing cell with problem and yellow collection view with proper shadow. I went through many posts but unable to get solution that can get shadow similar to collection view.

**For Collection view that is embedded in UIView and proper shadow**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    enclosureView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: enclosureView.bounds).cgPath

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    enclosureView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemGray2.cgColor
    enclosureView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    enclosureView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    enclosureView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    enclosureView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    enclosureView.cornerRadius = 10

}
```

**For Collection view cell having UIImage and UILabel.**

UIImage is embedded in UIView. I want shadow around image and not around cell.

```
class cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.layer.masksToBounds = false 
        self.clipsToBounds = false

        image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.backgroundColor = .clear

        imageEnclosureView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        imageEnclosureView.clipsToBounds = false
        imageEnclosureView.layer.shadowRadius = 5 
        imageEnclosureView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        imageEnclosureView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemGray2.cgColor
        imageEnclosureView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        imageEnclosureView.backgroundColor = .clear 
        
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
            
        self.imageEnclosureView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: imageEnclosureView.bounds,
            cornerRadius: 10
            ).cgPath

    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Use a "Dummy" UIView underneath your view hierarchy and add the shadow to that UIView and leave the UIImageView without shadow. [link](https://fluffy.es/rounded-corner-shadow/)

Comment: I am already doing that. I just figured setting clipsToBounds to false for collection view solves the issue.